# browser feature detection with try catch(e)

Tags: javascript

If a browser don't support Blob(), make the body content "Sorry your browser isn't supported :(".

Is this a good way to do so?

```
try {
  var isSupported = !! new Blob();
} catch (e) {
  document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>Sorry your browser isn\'t supported :(</h1>";
}
```

Or you  would suggest some other methods.

Comment: Or you could print the content on the top of HTML page with styling content like the one shown in StackOverflow when JS is not enabled.

Comment: Some browsers support obsolete BlobBuilder instead of the Blob constructor. Don't you want to support that as well?

Comment: @JustAndrei no I don't want to support them!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach:

```
if (window.Blob === undefined) {
    document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>Sorry your browser isn\'t supported :(</h1>";
}
```

Comment: how about (!window.Blob) { }

Comment: @b134692, this may generate an exception.